# Repeater set back ground of row and deselect the previous one in client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have a repeater control. On clicking the row should set the background color of this or and clicking the another row should unselect the previous selected row. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to be like this?

```js
$('#list li').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    
});
```

```css
#list {width:500px;margin:50px auto;}
#list li {margin:10px 0;padding:10px;background:#f0f0f0;color:#000;}

.active {background:#F60 !important;color:#FFF !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
    <li>row1</li>
    <li>row2</li>
    <li>row3</li>
    <li>row4</li>
    <li>row5</li>
    <li>row6</li>
    <li>row7</li>
  </ul>
```